# How can i apply css style for pageBlock title? can i use image as pageblock title?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I want to apply some styles to PageBlock title like changing font color, style and background color. and Can I assign image or logo as pageblock title.. Give me some working example.

this is my code: 
[image: this is my code]

This is the output
[image: this is my output]

I want apply same style effects to the title also..

Comment: can u share your current code and highlight where you need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may one to try using apex:facet to override pageBlock Title

```
 <apex:pageBlock  >
      <apex:facet name="header">
          <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.SiteSamples, 'img/force_logo.gif')}"/>
         </apex:facet>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorPageBlock(pageblock, color) {
if (pageblock != null) pageblock.firstChild.style.cssText = "background-color: " + color + ";";
}
```

[image]

```
apex:page standardController="Account">



function colorPageBlock(pageblock, color) {
if (pageblock != null) pageblock.firstChild.style.cssText = “background-color: ” + color + “;”;

}










colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.redSection}"), "red");





colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.greenSection}"), "green");





colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.orangeSection}"), "orange");
```

Comment: i guess it would help out out

Answer (score -2):

You can apply CSS to Pageblock header like following:

```
.pbHeader {

  //put your custom css here

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. it seems quite simple.. but could you provide an example for a better understanding..